# gxt (ext gwt) Grid and column width

Tags: grid, width, gxt

I am trying to create a grid that fills the width of a `ContentPanel`. The grid should have two columns of equal size that span the entire width of the grid. Resizing the browser window should update the grid size accordingly. I would expect the code below to accomplish this, but the grid does not grow on browser resize and there is a `~15px` gap between the second column and the right edge of the grid.

Any ideas?

```java
public class MyGrid extends ContentPanel {

@Override
protected void onRender(Element parent, int index) {
    super.onRender(parent, index);

    setLayout(new FillLayout());
    ColumnConfig c1 = new ColumnConfig("value","value", 50);
    ColumnConfig c2 = new ColumnConfig("value1","value1", 50);
    ListStore<ModelData> store = new ListStore<ModelData>();
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
      BaseModelData data = new BaseModelData();
      data.set("value", "value");
      data.set("value1", "value1");
      store.add(data);
    }
    Grid<ModelData> grid = new Grid<ModelData>(store, new ColumnModel(Arrays.asList(new ColumnConfig[] {c1, c2})));
    grid.setAutoHeight(true);
    grid.setAutoWidth(true);
    grid.getView().setAutoFill(true);
    add(grid); 
}
```

}

Comment: what version of gxt do you use ? 2.5/3.0?                                         LE: I think not 3.0 .. I would recommend you to use FitLayout() in stead of FillLayout

Comment: gxt 2.2.5. Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not seeing any difference in behavior with FitLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the extra space on the right of the table is `grid.setAutoHeight()`. Remove this and it will be gone. Getting the table to resize with the browser seems to require the use of a `Viewport` (I dont understand why the `ContentPanel` would grow without the grid in the code above). This code accomplishes what I was trying to do:

```java
public class MyGrid extends Viewport {

  @Override
  protected void onRender(Element parent, int index) {
    super.onRender(parent, index);

    setLayout(new FitLayout());
    ColumnConfig c1 = new ColumnConfig("value","value", 50);
    ColumnConfig c2 = new ColumnConfig("value1","value1", 50);
    ListStore<ModelData> store = new ListStore<ModelData>();
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
      BaseModelData data = new BaseModelData();
      data.set("value", "value");
      data.set("value1", "value1");
      store.add(data);
    }
    final Grid<ModelData> grid = new Grid<ModelData>(store, new ColumnModel(Arrays.asList(new ColumnConfig[] {c1, c2})));
    grid.getView().setAutoFill(true);
    ContentPanel panel = new ContentPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FitLayout());
    panel.add(grid);
    add(panel);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
grid.getView().setForceFit(true);
```

Grid will fit its container. Also you really should use other layout for container to make inner elements fit container (FitLayout, BorderLayout, RowLayout are acceptable)

Comment: I tried changing to FitLayout and using setForceFit with no change in behavior. Here is a screenshot of how the table renders: [link](http://imgur.com/NwOGv) -- notice the extra space on the right. And here is a shot of how it looks after resizing the browser: [link](http://imgur.com/VCzXR)