# Sencha GXT grid - gap in column header menu and 2nd column header

Tags: gxt

I am using Sencha GXT 4.0.2. I have added Grid inside a BorderLayoutContainer. When the UI is rendered, there is a small gap between the column header context menu arrow and next column header. For eg. width of `<tr>` is set to 100px, but width of `<div>` in header is 87px.

Following is the flow of control:
view -> BorderLayoutContainer -> BorderLayoutContainer -> FlowLayoutContainer ( as center layout data) -> Grid ( as widget )

When I add the editor to this grid, and start editing, all the columns of the selected row and its editors are shifted to left (as if they are inline with the `<div>` element's width).

The problem I am facing is similar to what is posted in [gxt (ext gwt) Grid and column width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200817/gxt-ext-gwt-grid-and-column-width) for gwt ext, but my issue is with Sencha gxt.

Any help is much appreciated.

[header misalignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRNeo.png)

[image]

[editor-misalignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI4px.png)
[image]

Comment: The FlowLayoutContainer is not sending the size to the child container. If you had ViewPort -> BLC -> BLC -> SimpleContainer -> Grid it should work. Or any containers with layout data that sends the width and height to the child container.

Answer (score 0):

This particular problem occurs when the grid is not provided with a size from either the parent container or directly with grid.setPixelSize(int, int). You can test this out by setting grid.setPixelSize(500,500) and the columns and rows should be sized properly. If that doesn't work, a test case with the problem would be needed to replicate the issue.